# Google Sheets script to hide columns not working on onEdit()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have the following code to show or hide columns/rows in a sheet based on the contents of the first row/column (whether it's more than or less than 0) which works fine when called from an installable trigger, but as an `onEdit` function, it doesn't work.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid using installable triggers, as that doesn't copy with the sheet and it's primarily intended as a template to be repeatedly copied.

The data is held in the sheet "input" and then provides data for queries in the sheet "table" (which is protected); ideally, it should either run on edit (on the sheet input) or on a one-minute interval (which is the preferable option, but not if it involves using the triggers program as outlined above).

The current version as below doesn't create any error messages but doesn't function as intended either.

```
function onEdit(){
  hideEmptyRows(); 
  hideCols(); 
}


function hideCols() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('table');
  var totalsRow = 1;

  sh.getRange(totalsRow, 3, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()-3).getValues()[0]
    .forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (!el || el >= 1) sh.showColumns(i + 3)
    });

 sh.getRange(totalsRow, 3, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()-3).getValues()[0]
    .forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (!el || el <= 0) sh.hideColumns(i + 3)
    })
}


function hideEmptyRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Table");      // Enter sheet name
  var row = s.getRange('A:A').getValues();            // Enter 
   column letter that has the text "hide" and  "unhide"

   s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
   for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){s.showRows(i+1, 1); if(row[i] == 0) { s.hideRows(i+1, 1); }   // Value to hide
  
  }}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Your code should be working fine.
- However, it is suggested to take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e`. In your current solution, if you make any changes to **another** sheet, `onEdit` might alter the sheet `table`. Maybe this is a desired behaviour but I wouldn't recommend it.
- Another improvement you can make in this particular project, using the event object, is to execute the `forEach` part when there is a **change** in the **first** row. Namely, there is no need to execute a for loop that performs calculations for row 1, if for example, row 2 is edited.

### Solution:

Here I offer you a more maintainable/futureproof solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  const sheet_name = 'table';
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const totalsRow = 1;

  if(sh.getName() == sheet_name && row == totalsRow ){
  sh.getRange(totalsRow, 3, 1, sh.getMaxColumns()-3).getValues()[0]
    .forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (!el || el <= 0) sh.hideColumns(i + 3);
        if (!el || el > 0) sh.showColumns(i + 3);
    })
}
}
```

Comment: "However, it is suggested to take advantage of the event object e. In your current solution, if you make any changes to another sheet, onEdit might alter the sheet table. Maybe this is a desired behaviour but I wouldn't recommend it." 

That is indeed the desired behaviour! Table is a protected sheet which runs a query, and isn't edited directly. As a result, it does indeed need to check all columns rather than just the active one.

Comment: @MattBowyer "Table is a **protected** sheet." You really should mention that in your question. That is exactly why the previous version of this answer(installable trigger) worked for you. Also, the error would've been logged at view>executions. You should have mentioned that error also in your question

Comment: @TheMaster I feel like I have to rollback my answer.

Comment: @Marios As you wish. But You should explain why installable trigger is the answer(Which part required authorization).  I suggest a merge between current and old answer(as the part about event object still applies). But There won't be any interference on my part any more, regardless of what you choose to do.

Comment: @TheMaster I think I will change my answer later. If OP wants to improve his question and clarify the error, then his question might be reopened. I will change my answer if he decides to do so to match the new version of his question. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Marios - also, `!el || el <= 0` can be simplified : `!el || el < 0` (due to `!0 === true`) and, if `el` can be safely assumed to be numeric, even more : `el <= 0`. Or, even better : `el > 0 ? sh.showColumns(i + 3) : sh.hideColumns(i + 3)`